# Loops and inline functions

Tags: c++, c, loops, inline-functions

Why is it that a function with loops cannot be made inline?  Is it due to a performance issue or is there any other reason?

Comment: "Why a function with loops cannot be made as inline" - That's not true. Where did you hear that from?

Comment: C++, C99, and GNU C each have support for inline functions. Different compilers vary in how complex a function they can manage to inline. [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inline_function)

Comment: can you provide an specific example?

Comment: I wonder what "Loop Unrolling" means then

Comment: @Cthulhu they're related by the same heuristics that determine if a function is inlined. For example if the loop can be unrolled, and the the function is small enough to be inlined, then it _will_ be inlined, even if it contains loops.

Comment: Maybe OP means why can't a recursive function be inlined?

Comment: @Aniket: functions containing loops may be inlined even if the loops cannot be unrolled.

Comment: @Aniket Loop unrolling (AFAIK) is a decision made at a much lower level, at a much later stage, so I thought the compiler wouldn't be able to really tell if the loop can/cannot be unrolled.

Comment: @Nawaz that then, is the answer to OP's question

Comment: @Aniket: Posted it as an answer.

Comment: @Nawaz : http://pastebin.com/BuruPdi9

Comment: @Nawaz same heuristics guided both loop unrolling and function inlining.

Comment: The main reason might be that you use an old compiler, like Turbo-C++.

Comment: @Aniket: How can you said that? Try `inline` keyword with latest version of gcc.

Comment: @Nawaz I am using pretty late version of gcc-4.5.3, I _could_ have inlined it. My point was, it will inline the function if we unroll the loop. I am not saying that's the only way a function becomes eligible for inlining. see where I am getting at? Its _not_ mandatory that unrolling will make a function eligible for inlining.  BUT it can be one of the ways you can make it eligible. Which my post suggests

Comment: I think the OP is reading some very old C++ books or using old C++ compilers. I also have the impression that some 90's C++ books claim that loops cannot be put into inline functions.

Answer (score 6):

Functions containing loops may be inlined even if the loops cannot be unrolled. Whoever said otherwise is wrong.

Answer (score 4):

A function with loops can be made inline, But every time a function is called, there is a certain amount of performance overhead that occurs. This is because the CPU must store the address of the current instruction it is executing (so it knows where to return to later) along with other registers, all the function parameters must be created and assigned values, and the program has to branch to a new location. Iline  Code written in-place is significantly faster.

Because of the potential for code bloat, inlining a function is best suited to short functions (eg. no more than a few lines) that are typically called inside loops and do not branch. Also note that the inline key word is only a recommendation — the compiler is free to ignore your request to inline a function. This is likely to be the result if you try to inline a lengthy function!

C++ offers a way to combine the advantages of functions with the speed of code written in-place: inline functions. The inline keyword is used to request that the compiler treat your function as an inline function. When the compiler compiles your code, all inline functions are expanded in-place — that is, the function call is replaced with a copy of the contents of the function itself, which removes the function call overhead! The downside is that because the inline function is expanded in-place for every function call, this can make your compiled code quite a bit larger, especially if the inline function is long and/or there are many calls to the inline function.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>
using namespace std;

inline void inlineFunction()
{
    int loopCounter = 0;
     while(loopCounter<5 )
     {
         loopCounter++;
         cout<<"Inline loop "<<loopCounter<<" \n";
     }
}

void regularFunction()
{
    int loopCounter = 0;
     while(loopCounter<5 )
     {
         loopCounter++;
         cout<<"regular  "<<loopCounter<<" \n";
     }
}

int main()
{

    clock_t start;
    clock_t end;
    clock_t duration;

    cout << "Running inline function  ..." << endl;
    start = clock();

     inlineFunction();

    end = clock();
    duration = end - start;
    cout << "Time elapsed: " << duration << " ticks. \n" << endl;

    cout << "Running function  ..." << endl;
    start = clock();

    regularFunction();

    end = clock();
    duration = end - start;
    cout << "Time elapsed: " << duration << " ticks.\n" << endl;

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I don't think this proves anything without showing the disassembly. The compiler is free to inline both, or neither of them.

Comment: I think `inline` keyword only suggests the compiler to inline the function. Does not guarantee it.

Comment: What if the `loopcounter` variable is a function parameter? What if it depends on the program input? Can the function be inlined in such a case?